# What would happen if while making a connection between memory and CPU, the address lines get's interchanged

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

While making a circuit connection between Micro Processor and Memory Chips, the Address Lines A0 and A1 got interchanged. Means A0 of address bus got connected wrongly with A1 of Memory chip and A1 of address bus got wrongly connected with A0. Same error has been committed for both RAM and ROM chips. What would happen ?

Comment: How do these memories get their contents, and has the swap been anticipated? (I've admired such having been done on purpose.) (What exactly does make a change to "something right" an error?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the previous comment. Regarding the question, I don't think doing the same reversing error to RAM & ROM will fix it. However, I think following the block diagram (of the motherboard I guess)  can tell u exactly why will happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RAM it's not much of a problem. True, address 0 will be kept in cell 1 in the RAM, but who cares -- whenever the CPU access address 0 it will be directed to the same place, whatever its name is.

With ROM this might be a problem, since the ROM is pre-coded with content. When the CPU access address 0 of the ROMO it expects to see there the first byte of the ROM's content, however, it will retrieve the second, which might fail the program.